# Checking a Javascript variable when submitting a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a simple HTML form that uses jQuery functions to validate the form.

[JsFiddle here:](http://jsfiddle.net/GTQN2/2/)

You will notice in the jQuery code, I have a variable called `flag`, which is either set to 0 OR 1.

```
jQuery(function () {
jQuery("#ValidField").validate({
expression: "if (VAL){flag=1; return true; }else{flag=0; return false;}",
message: "Please enter the Required field"
});
jQuery("#ValidNumber").validate({
expression: "if (!isNaN(VAL) && VAL){flag=1; return true; }else{flag=0; return false;}",
message: "Please enter a valid number"
});
jQuery("#ValidInteger").validate({
expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[0-9]*$/) && VAL){flag=1; return true; }else{flag=0; return false;}",
message: "Please enter a valid integer"
});

jQuery("#ValidSelection").validate({
expression: "if (VAL != '0'){flag=1; return true; }else{flag=0; return false;}",
message: "Please make a selection"
});

jQuery("#ValidRadio").validate({
expression: "if (isChecked(SelfID)){flag=1; return true; }else{flag=0; return false;}",
message: "Please select a radio button"
});
jQuery("#ValidCheckbox").validate({
expression: "if (isChecked(SelfID)){flag=1; return true; }else{flag=0; return false;}",
message: "Please check atleast one checkbox"
});

jQuery('.AdvancedForm').validated(function () {
if (flag == 1) alert("Use this call RIGHT HERE to make AJAX submissions.");
});
});
```

Note that the `if (flag == 1)` in the last jQuery statement is not necessary. I put it in there to see if the JS recognizes the variable (which it does).

**How can check if flag==0 AND call a Javascript alert to say "Errors on Page"???**

Thank you in advance.

I updated the code to fix the (flag == 1) syntax.

Comment: FYI: When you say `if (flag=1)` you're *assigning* the value 1 to `flag`. You need to say `if (flag==1)` to compare.

Comment: Furthermore saying `if(flag = 1)` is the same as `if(true)`.  That is because assigning the one to flag will always return true due to the assignment happening.

Comment: This is not a good way of validating a form. A user could easily get past this validator and submit garbage. You can still use this, but you must also validate inputs from the server side as well.

Comment: I updated the code to fix the (flag == 1) syntax error. I realize that you need to validate at the server side as well, but that is fixed in the PHP/MySQL side. I am having trouble with the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
if (flag) {
   alert("Use this call RIGHT HERE to make AJAX submissions.");
} else{
   alert("Flag was 0 or what error message you want to show");
}
```

As mentioned before, you need to use `==` for comparison rather than `=` which is for assignment. However, since flag is a boolean and will be either 1 or 0, you can just use if(flag) for true and evaluate the false case with an else statement.

**Edit**: To check when invalid, you can use the invalidHandler function (this applies to the jQuery Validation Plugin):

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  invalidHandler: function() {
    alert("There were errors on the page");
  }
});
```

See: http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.numberOfInvalids/

**Edit**: The validation for jQuery Live Form Validation.
By default this validation is live which will display the message when validation fails as you fill out the form. You could probably add a listener to the form submit and check for the validation error classes.

```
jQuery('.AdvancedForm').submit(function(){
     if(jQuery('.AdvancedForm').find('.ValidationErrors').length){
        alert('There were errors on your form');
     }
});
```

See: http://www.geektantra.com/2009/09/jquery-live-form-validation/

Comment: I think the OP's question is where to do such a check.

Comment: It can't be in jQuery('.AdvancedForm').validated(function () { because the validated function will be executed when the form is validated. If the form is validated, flag will always be 1.

Comment: yes. This doesn't answer the OPs question, which is: "How can check if flag=0 AND call a Javascript alert to say 'Errors on Page'???"

Comment: @Jonathan M  You are absolutely correct!!! Furthermore jQuery('.AdvancedForm').validated(function () is in the jQuery Library, and I don't want to go changing or adding to the jQuery code {in case I update the jQuery Library}.